# React native dropdown-picker

Tags: react-native

When I am  using the dropdown  picker I am getting  this  error log

1 of 2  Render Error Cannot read property 'default' of undefined  181

```
});  182  > 183  const  THEME = useMemo (() => THEMES  184  185  const 

ICON = useMemo (() => THEMES [1  186  /**  C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Summer Project\HR MSystem\node_modules\react-native-drop down-picker\src\components\Picker.js  (183:46)  Call Stack  useMemo$argument_0  C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Sum...components\Picker.js:183:46  mountMemo  C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Sum...tiveRenderer-dev.js:11819:29  HooksDispatcher OnMount InDEV.useMemo
```

I am trying  to use a React native  dropdown  picker

Comment: Please share the code that throws said error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error itself is just telling you that somewhere in your code you wrote ```somevariable.default``` or something similar, but ```somevariable``` was undefined, so there was no ```default``` property in it

Comment: @Haleema Can you provide some code so we can check

Answer (score 0):

Some basic help, but make sure you have imported react native dropdown picker correctly using:
npm i react-native-dropdown-picker

There could be some error with how THEMES is being accessed or the object iteself, if it isn't defined properly.

Also not a fix to your issue, but I have found success using this library if you aren't able to get the one you're using to work:
"react-native-element-dropdown"